# Custom Spring RedisHash with multiple IDs for a parametrized key

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I have some Redis hash keys which are defined as `Class:<class_id>:Student:<student_id>`. I'm having trouble defining this parametrized RedisHash in Springboot for keys like this. So far I've only been defining hashes like these which have no issue.

```
@RedisHash(value = "Class")  // It becomes Redis key Class:1
public class Class implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long classId;
    private String className;
    private String classLeaderName;

}
```

For my required Redis hash, I want to define something like this:

```
@RedisHash(value = "Class:<class_id>:Student:<student_id>")  // It becomes Redis key Class:1:Student:21
public class ClassStudent implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long classId;

    @Id
    private Long studentId;

    private String studentName;
    private String studentSurname;

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your best approach would be create a new variable composed by the other 2, like this:

```
private Long classId;

private Long studentId;

@Id
private Long id = "$classId:$studentId";

private String studentName;

private String studentSurname;
```